# For loop end value not correctly evaluated if Collection.Count in Excel 64 bits

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that works as expected in Office 365 32 Bits, but fails in Office 365 64 bits

---

**Module module1:**

```
Function Test()
    'Init
    Dim c As myrows, r As myrow
    
    Set c = New myrows
    For i = 1 To 6
        Set r = New myrow
        r.Visible = ((i Mod 2) = 0)
        c.Add r
        Set r = Nothing
    Next i
    
    'Tests
    
    Debug.Print "Total items in c:", c.Count
    Debug.Print "Visibles items in c:", c.VisiblesItems.Count
    
    'not working in Office 64 bits
    For i = 1 To c.VisiblesItems.Count
        Debug.Print "Test 1: Visible item: ", i
    Next i
    
    'working
    Dim ec As Long
    ec = c.VisiblesItems.Count
    For i = 1 To ec
        Debug.Print "Test 2: Visible item: ", i
    Next i
    
    'also working
    Dim vi As myrows
    Set vi = c.VisiblesItems
    For i = 1 To vi.Count
        Debug.Print "Test 3: Visible item: ", i
    Next i

End Function
```

**Class myrow:**

```
Private mVisible As Boolean

Public Property Get Visible() As Boolean
    Visible = mVisible
End Property
Public Property Let Visible(v As Boolean)
    mVisible = v
End Property
```

**Class myrows:**

```
Dim c As Collection

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Count = c.Count
End Property

Public Function Item(ByVal index As Variant) As myrow
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Item = c.Item(index)
End Function

Public Sub Add(ByRef r As myrow)
    c.Add r
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(ByVal index As Variant)
    c.Remove index
End Sub

Public Function VisiblesItems() As myrows
    Dim v As myrows
    Set v = New myrows
    If c Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        If c.Item(i).Visible Then v.Add c.Item(i)
    Next i
    Set VisiblesItems = v
    Set v = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set c = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set c = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

The expected behavior is to display:

```
Total items in c:            6 
Visibles items in c:         3 
Test 1: Visible item:        1 
Test 1: Visible item:        2 
Test 1: Visible item:        3 
Test 2: Visible item:        1 
Test 2: Visible item:        2 
Test 2: Visible item:        3 
Test 3: Visible item:        1 
Test 3: Visible item:        2 
Test 3: Visible item:        3
```

but the same code in Office 365 64 bits displays only the two fist lines, the For loop end condition seemingly evaluated to 0 (or less) even when `c.VisiblesItems.Count` is 3.

```
Total items in c:            6 
Visibles items in c:         3 
Test 2: Visible item:        1 
Test 2: Visible item:        2 
Test 2: Visible item:        3 
Test 3: Visible item:        1 
Test 3: Visible item:        2 
Test 3: Visible item:        3
```

In my production code (much complicated), the For loop end condition can also be evaluated to a value over `c.VisiblesItems.Count`, breaking the execution when trying of access non existing items.

I can easyly solve this by putting `c.VisiblesItems.Count` in a variable and using this variable as end condition, but is this a (known) bug of VBA for Office 64bits or is my code wrong at the beginning?

Edit: Edited code to check GSerg comment

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour if you save `c.VisiblesItems` (as opposed to `c.VisiblesItems.Count`) in a variable of type `myrows`?

Comment: @cserg I tested it and using c.VisiblesItems also works (see edited question)

Comment: Time to [debug your small program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You have F8 and the watch window, use them and observe where it goes wrong.

Comment: @GSerg: I did. When I run the program step by step, the evaluation of the Count property for the row `For i = 1 To c.VisiblesItems.Count` returns `3`. Even though, the next step put me outside the loop as if the returned value was 0.

Comment: If you instruct the watch window to evaluate `c.VisiblesItems.Count`, it will query yet another collection from your class (because it creates a new collection for the results each time), so that is not actually valid. Place some `debug.print` in `Public Function VisiblesItems()` and see when and how it is called and what it prepares to return.

Comment: I know VisiblesItems is a temporary object so I didn't the watch window for that. I used a breakpoint on the return of the Count Property to check the value returned, and it is the correct value. Every breakpoint and debug.print inside myrows code displays the expected 3 value. And the code still skip the full first For loop.